# removing all options of select box except 1st option

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to empty select options when:

id "mClick" is selected, id's "sClick", "cClick" and "srClick" will be emptied.

id "sClick" is selected, id's "cClick" and "srClick" will be emptied.

id "cClick" is selected, id "srClick" will be emptied.

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" id="lForm">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="module" id="mClick">
                <option value="">Select Mod</option>
                <option value="1">Mod 1</option>
                <option value="2">Mod 2</option>
                <option value="3">Mod 3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="state" id="sClick">
                <option value="">Select State</option>
                <option value="1">State 1</option>
                <option value="2">State 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="city" id="cClick">
                <option value="">Select City</option>
                <option value="1">City 1</option>
                <option value="2">City 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="services" id="srClick">
                <option value="">Select Services</option>
                <option value="1">Services 1</option>
                <option value="2">Services 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

in scenario 3, i used this function, but it deleted all, except the last select. Any idea's what i'm missing? Thanks

```
$('#lForm select[id!="mClick"] select[id!="sClick"] select[id!="cClick"] option[value!=""]').remove().end();
```

Comment: sorry typo, removed it, but still don't work.

Comment: your element ids are different i.e. `makeClick` in jquery and `mClick` in HTML

Comment: If they're emptied, then how are they ever repopulated?

Comment: using ajax get, here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/qVaaJ/7/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way to clear the options in the way you're describing is by using `options.length = 1`. Also, you can leverage the fact that each drop down clears the ones that logically follow it, so that you only need to declare a single change handler.

```
$('#lForm select').on('change', function() {
  if (this.selectedIndex > 0) {
    var $others = $(this).closest('table').find('select'),
    current = $others.index(this); // find current

    while (++current < $others.length) {
      // for each following drop down
      $others.get(current).options.length = 1;
    }
  }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/apubic/1/)

I'm not sure how you're going to repopulate the drop downs though :)

Comment: works! thanks alot! going to populate it using ajax GET, just didn't want server to send an empty <option> tag. thought it would be better to clear it using jquery. so "options.length = 1" deletes it by setting length to 1?

Comment: @user2035819 Yeah, this is how arrays are "clipped" in JavaScript :)

Answer (score 187):

Try this

```js
yourSelect.find('option').not(':first').remove();
```

Comment: Perfect as well, but will mention (and I'm not quite sure why) but you don't have to use .find('option').  It also works just for the select.  Example for when I need to completely repopulate the list except the first option, because of Apple's non-compliant browsers that ignore CSS display property: jQ("#jobFilter>select").not(':first').remove().append(jobOptions)

Answer (score 44):

I was looking for one line code, what I found after lots of research is the Simplest and Best one line code to remove everything except first.

***JQuery,***

```
$('#ddlId option:not(:first)').remove();
```

Answer (score 19):

you can use the greater than `:gt()` selector of jQuery for this

```
$('#lForm select[id!="makeClick"] select[id!="stateClick"] select[id!="cityClick"] option:gt(0)').remove().end();
```

This will remove all options that are greater than 0

Comment: changed to :gt() http://jsfiddle.net/qVaaJ/6/ the last 2 select, are totally emptied. when a mod is selected. i'm trying to keep all value="" visible

Answer (score 14):

You can use `not(:first)`

```
$('#lForm select[id!="makeClick"] select[id!="stateClick"] select[id!="cityClick"]  option:not(:first)').remove().end();
```

Comment: city and state get totally emptied when a mod is selected. http://jsfiddle.net/qVaaJ/8/

Answer (score 5):

It's Work

```
$('#mClick').change(function () {
    $('#sClick, #cClick, #srClick').find("option:gt(0)").remove();
});
$('#sClick').change(function () {
    $('#cClick, #srClick').find("option:gt(0)").remove();
});
$('#cClick').change(function () {
    $('#srClick').find("option:gt(0)").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

asssign general class to your Dropdown then

$('.general option[value!=""]').remove();

this will remove all options except first one whose value is empty
Hope this will helps

Comment: I used this because first value was empty

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#lForm select').change(function(){
   var $selects = $('#lForm select');
   var idx = $selects.index(this);

   // Use `val` function to clear the selected values or Use `remove` function to remove the element.
   $selects.filter(':gt(' + idx +')').val('');

});
```