# How to remove all element from select option without first one using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need one help. I need to remove all element from select option except first one using Jquery/Javascript.I am explaining my code below.

```
<select class="form-control" name="spacearea" id="spaceStatusID" onchange="removeBorder('spaceStatusID');">
<option value="" selected>Select your space status</option>
<option value="1">Available</option>
<option value="2">Rented</option>
 </select>
```

From above I need to remove all element within select tag except first one `i.e-<option value="" selected>Select your space status</option>`  using Jquery.Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35528464/519413

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example. Use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) with [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#spaceStatusID').find('option:gt(0)').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" name="spacearea" id="spaceStatusID" onchange="removeBorder('spaceStatusID');">
  <option value="" selected>Select your space status</option>
  <option value="1">Available</option>
  <option value="2">Rented</option>
</select>
```